# SyntaxError: invalid syntax while trying to release webcam

Tags: python, opencv, detection, face-detection, webcam-capture

I have written a code which is planned to perform face, eye and smile detection by capturing frames from my laptop's webcam. However, when I'm done, the below code does not run and returns an Invalid Syntax Error. 
I don't know how to fix this problem because the line returns the error is just the same everywhere on the internet as I do. But still I might be doing something wrong somewhere.(I'm a very new to Python by the way!)

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np

face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
smile_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_smile.xml')

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   

img_counter = 0

while True:
    #Capture frame by frame
    _, frame = video_capture.read()
    im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    #Detect faces, eyes and smiles in input frame
     faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(im_gray, 
                                              scaleFactor = 1.5, 
                                              minNeighbors = 5,
                                              minSize=(30, 30),
                                            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

     eyes = eye_classifier.detectMultiScale(im_gray, 
                                            scaleFactor = 1.5,
                                            minNeighbors = 3,
                                            minSize=(10, 10),
                                            maxSize=(15,15),
                                          flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

     smiles = smile_classifier.detectMultiScale(im_gray,
                                                scaleFactor = 1.5,
                                                minNeighbors = 3,
                                                minSize = (5,5),
                                                maxSize = (10,15),
                                         flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for x, y, w, h in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Draw a rectangle around the eyes
    for ex, ey, ew, eh in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (ex, ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0,0,255), 1)         

        # Draw a rectangle around the smiles    
        for fx,fy,fw,fh in smiles:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (fx,fy), (fx+fw, fy+fh), (110,100,200), 1.5)

            # Display the resulting frame
            cv2.imshow('Our Face Detector', frame)

            if k == 27: #ESC Pressed
                break
            elif k == 32: # SPACE pressed
                img_name = "FaceDetect_webcam_{}.png".format(img_counter)
                cv2.imwrite(img_name,frame)
                print("{} saved!".format(img_name, frame)
                img_counter += 1
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here's the error 1:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Top Secret/EE 492/ANACONDA-PYTHON-OPENCV/untitled0.py", line 69
img_counter += 1
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the error 2:

```
File "<ipython-input-21-a9c9ddf625b0>", line 64
video_capture.release()
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The line `print("{} saved!".format(img_name, frame)` is missing a closing `)`.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

> print("{} saved!".format(img_name, frame)

(As mentioned in the comment) a ")" is missing.

Also, in the same line the syntax of using ".format()" is *not right* as you have given two variables inside the ".format" parentheses namely "img_name" and "frame" but there is only one "{}" within print's " ". So there should be two "{}" if you want to print the values of two variables. Note that this will not throw any error, but just pointing it out.

Hope this helps.

edit:

Check the indentation in your code.

After

> ```
> k = cv2.waitKey(1)
> ```

there is a space before the "faces = face_classifier....." line. (I do not know whether this happened while pasting the code here or it was like that in your editor also)

Also, I don't think you need to nest this for loop inside a previous loop. It should be within "while loop indentation"

> for fx,fy,fw,fh in smiles:
>               cv2.rectangle(frame, (fx,fy), (fx+fw, fy+fh), (110,100,200), 1.5)

Then put the next following lines of code also in the "while loop indentation"

So finally your code will look like this:

```
while True:
    #Capture frame by frame
    _, frame = video_capture.read()
    im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    #Detect faces, eyes and smiles in input frame
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(im_gray, 
                                          scaleFactor = 1.5, 
                                          minNeighbors = 5,
                                          minSize=(30, 30),
                                        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

    eyes = eye_classifier.detectMultiScale(im_gray, 
                                        scaleFactor = 1.5,
                                        minNeighbors = 3,
                                        minSize=(10, 10),
                                        maxSize=(15,15),
                                      flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

    smiles = smile_classifier.detectMultiScale(im_gray,
                                            scaleFactor = 1.5,
                                            minNeighbors = 3,
                                            minSize = (5,5),
                                            maxSize = (10,15),
                                     flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for x, y, w, h in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Draw a rectangle around the eyes
    for ex, ey, ew, eh in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (ex, ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0,0,255), 1)         

    # Draw a rectangle around the smiles    
    for fx,fy,fw,fh in smiles:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (fx,fy), (fx+fw, fy+fh), (110,100,200), 1.5)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Our Face Detector', frame)

    if k == 27: #ESC Pressed
        break
    elif k == 32: # SPACE pressed
        img_name = "FaceDetect_webcam_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name,frame)
        print("{} saved!".format(img_name, frame)
        img_counter += 1
video_capture.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I made the required changes according to your guidance but it still throws the same error as I stated the Error 2 above. (Sorry for multiple commenting and amendments. I was trying to add the Error here. So what's wrong with the syntax of video_capture.release() ?? Thank you anyway!